# Can a RDLC with a StoredProcedure dataset handle OUTPUT Parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, rdlc

I have many RDLC reports based on a StoredProcedure dataset on SqlServer.

My StoredProc have an OUTPUT parameter which receive an XML string with a list of ids to filter my table  `<ListXML><ItemId>10</ItemId><ItemId>11</ItemId></ListXML>`.

I also want to show on my report header the formatted list of ids so users can see what they sent `10, 11`.

So far, i'm handling the case with a CustomCode in the report properties using the System.Xml reference but i don't like having to use an external reference (especially while deploying the report on the server), the overhead of copy-pasting the code in each and every report and i'm concerned that my team will forget to copy the custom code and develop other solutions to handle the problem. I'd rather have my StoredProcedure return me the formatted string of Id to display on my report header.

i tested the case with a dummy sp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rep_Test]
    @test VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT        
AS
BEGIN
    set @test = 'hello'

    select top 10 * from item
END
```

and it revealed to me that it doesn't work right of the bat. Visual Studio does set 'Hello' as 'default value' to my parameter in the report but if i give a value to my report parameter it will not be overidden by the stored procedure.

Any insight on the subject or any other solution to handle the problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.   An RDLC cannot handle OUTPUT parameters in its dataset.   You have to use a workaround.

One workaround is to employ a wrapper procedure that reads the resultset of the inner procedure, and adds another column with the value of the output parameter in every row.

A more detailed description with code can be found [here](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/08/use-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-ssrs/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will be looking for a nice work around and look through the article you linked :)